# How to handle different port by Golang Gorilla mux?

Tags: go

I try to separate internal use and external use API in different port.

For example external in port 80 , and internal in port 5487.

I use **github.com/gorilla/mux** for url routing.

I try to create two different route

```golang
func main() {

    internal := mux.NewRouter()
    external := mux.NewRouter()

    internal.HandleFunc("/foo", logging(foo))
    internal.HandleFunc("/bar", logging(bar))

    external.HandleFunc("/monitor", monitor())

    http.ListenAndServe(":80", internal)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", external)
}
```

But it's turn out that the second server is unreachable code.

So how can I create two different port in go ?

Thanks

Comment: How this solution can scale?

Comment: What do you mean scale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use goroutine.

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "net/http"

        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    )

    func main() {

        internal := mux.NewRouter()
        external := mux.NewRouter()

        internal.HandleFunc("/foo", logging(foo))
        internal.HandleFunc("/bar", logging(bar))

        external.HandleFunc("/monitor", monitor())

        go http.ListenAndServe(":80", internal)

        go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", external)

        select{} // block forever to prevent exiting
    }
```

Comment: How to prevent exit ? when put http.ListenAndServe into go routine ?

Comment: @howie i mistake. add `exit := make(chan bool)` for prevent exit.

Comment: You can eliminate the code related to the `exit` channel by calling `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", external)` directly at the end of the function.  Do not ignore the errors returned from `http.ListenAndServe`.  Do something like: `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", internal))`

Comment: No need to wrap the thing in a func. You can just `go http.ListenAndServer(":80", internal)`.

Also, to block exiting you don't need a fake channel. You can `select {}`

Comment: @hasen added a log.Fatal wrapper to catch common usage errors like "port in use"

Answer (score 0):

try `go routines` :)

> Agreed, to `wait` and `listen` you can add a `channel` which will continue to listen infinietly

```
infinite_wait := make(chan string)

go func(){
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", internal)
}()

go func(){
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", external)
}() 

<-infinite_wait
```

Comment: this code isn't tested, but should work, ideally

Comment: It's not work ~ http.ListenAndServe should bock and listen . But if I put into go routine this program will finish and exit

Comment: @howie agreed, I edited my answer, added a `channel`